# Getting omnicppcomplete and ctags to work in VIM

Tags: c++, vim, ctags, omnicomplete

Here's my .vimrc

```
syntax on
set number
set nowrap
set autoindent
" configure tags - add additional tags here or comment out not-used ones
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/cpp_files
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/cpp_src/
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/qt
" build tags of your own project with Ctrl-F12
map C-F12 :!ctags -R --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .CR

" OmniCppComplete
let OmniCpp_NamespaceSearch = 1
let OmniCpp_GlobalScopeSearch = 1
let OmniCpp_ShowAccess = 1
let OmniCpp_ShowPrototypeInAbbr = 1 " show function parameters
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteDot = 1 " autocomplete after .
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteArrow = 1 " autocomplete after ->
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteScope = 1 " autocomplete after ::
let OmniCpp_DefaultNamespaces = ["std", "_GLIBCXX_STD"]
" automatically open and close the popup menu / preview window
au CursorMovedI,InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|silent! pclose|endif
set completeopt=menuone,menu,longest,preview

autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType html set omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType css set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
autocmd FileType xml set omnifunc=xmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
autocmd FileType c set omnifunc=ccomplete#Complete
au BufNewFile,BufRead,BufEnter *.cpp,*.hpp set omnifunc=omni#cpp#complete#Main
autocmd FileType cpp set omnifunc=cppcomplete#CompleteCPP
```

I've followed [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C++_code_completion) guide for getting it to work, but nothing really happens. As you can see I've tried a variation of autocmd and au type commands for this to work, but nothing actually happens. Am I doing something wrong? The paths in the set tags* lines are correct...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line should be the one that causes the problem:

```
autocmd FileType cpp set omnifunc=cppcomplete#CompleteCPP
```

You see, you have the following commands:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead,BufEnter *.cpp,*.hpp set omnifunc=omni#cpp#complete#Main
autocmd FileType cpp set omnifunc=cppcomplete#CompleteCPP
```

The thing is, the first autocommand is executed when entering a buffer with the extension "cpp" or "hpp". The second is executed when the filetype is set to cpp, which *always* happens *after* opening the buffer. It doesn't even matter how you order them, the second one will always be executed after the first one, so the `omnifunc` will always be set to `cppcomplete#completeCPP`, and you don't want that. You should replace *both* of these lines with this one line:

```
autocmd FileType cpp set omnifunc=omni#cpp#complete#Main
```

Just in case, if it still doesn't work, try only this instead:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead,BufEnter *.cpp,*.hpp set omnifunc=omni#cpp#complete#Main
```

For future debugging issues, a small tip: you can check the value of `omnifunc` by executing `set omnifunc`. That way, you can check if the completion function really is the one you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to try that out as soon as I get home.

Comment: Update: I tried this (both of the solutions), and when I type Ctrl-X; Ctrl-O, it says that that specific omnifunc is unknown. Does that mean that omnicppcomplete was installed incorrectly?

Comment: That's probably the case. Do you know where you put it? Are you using the pathogen plugin, a vimball...?

Comment: I'm using a .vim file, which I put in usr/share/vim/plugin.

Comment: That's really not enough for this plugin, there's a lot more than just a plugin file. You can read the instructions here: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520. You need to download a zip file and extract the entire thing in your `~/.vim` directory.